# Supplier Functional Interface

Tags: java-8, consumer, functional-interface, supplier

As we know `Consumer<T>` functional interface is used in `forEach()` so similarly does Java has a use case for `Supplier` other than the custom ones?

Comment: Here is every use of `java.util.function.Supplier` in the standard library for Java 19: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/class-use/Supplier.html

Comment: And for fun, here's the same for `java.util.function.Consumer`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/class-use/Consumer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Supplier<T> supplier)` can be used to provide a default value for an Optional if it is empty.

`java.util.stream.Stream.generate(Supplier<T> s)` can be used to generate a stream of values.